# Run method after first method finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, npm

I am creating an npm package and am trying to get one method to execute or wait until after another method has been called and finished. Fe. in the following:

```
var package = require('myNpmPackage');
package.method1(options);
...
```

later, possibly in another file

```
package.method2();
```

In the above example. Suppose that `package.method1()` sets the overall package up by connecting to a server, kind of like mongoose and mongo. This means that `package.method2()` is going to run before `package.method1()` can successfully set everything up. How can I get `package.method2()` to execute, only after waiting for `package.method1()` to finish?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that can work is to use the async library although this would only work assuming that they are in the same file

From the documentation on their website:

```
async.auto(
    {
        package1: function (callback) {
            // call package1
            callback();
        },
        package2: [ "package1", function (callback) {
            // call package2
            callback();
        }]
    }, function (err/*, r*/) {
    }
);
```

the link is here: https://github.com/caolan/async#auto